# What about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\psi\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ as $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function, digamma-function

For integers $n\geq 1$ let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function, and let $\psi(z)$ the Digamma function, see its definition and how is denoted and typeset in Wolfram Language, if you need it from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html).

While I was doing calculations I found this problem:

*Calculate a good approximation of* $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\psi\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

My believe that why it is interesting is that [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) provide me approximations around $\frac{1}{2}$, with codes like this

`sum mu(n)/n  PolyGamma[0, 1+1/n], from n=1 to 5000`

> **Question.** My belief is that defining $$S:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\psi\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right),$$ then $$S=\frac{1}{2}.$$ Can you provide us and justify a good approximation of $S$, or well do you know how discard that $S=\frac{1}{2}$? If do you know that it was in the literature, refers it. **Many thanks.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}=0$, we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\psi\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left[\psi\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)+\gamma\right],$$ and the series is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$. Now
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\left[\psi\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)+\gamma\right]=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum^\infty_{k=1}\zeta(k+1)\frac{(-x)^k}{n^k},$$ from the Taylor series of the Digamma function. For $|x|<1$, this is absolutely convergent, and we can change the order of summation, so we get $$-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\zeta(k+1)(-x)^k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{k+1}}=-\sum^\infty_{k=1}(-x)^k=\frac{x}{1+x},$$ since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{k+1}}=\frac1{\zeta(k+1)}.$$
The limit for $x\rightarrow1$ is $1/2,$ indeed.

Comment: Many thanks for you answer, I am going to study it.

Comment: I've corrected the typo.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks.

Comment: This is my original problem. Equate $e^x=e^x$, where LHS is $(16)$ from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html), and RHS is the infinite product due to Sondow and Guillera, *Problem 11381* The American Mathematical MONTLHY (2008). Professor Sondow share it from his [homepage](http://home.earthlink.net/~jsondow/). Then take logarithms in our first equation, and also $\int_0^1$. Thus you've proved that our resulting RHS is also $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This morning I've forgotten my first equation, and now I see that  therefore so much that it could be much more easily deduced the result. Any case your calculations are remarkables.

Comment: A **consequence of the PNT** is if $f(z) = \frac{C}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (g(nz)-\frac{1}{n})$ converges uniformly for $|z| \ge |z_0|$ then $g(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) f(nz)$ for $|z| \ge |z_0|$. Here $z_0 = 1$ and $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}(\psi(1+\frac{1}{z})+\gamma) = \frac{\gamma}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (g(nz)-\frac{1}{n})$, $g(z) = \frac{1}{1+z}$.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

To confirm the result, I computed
$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{10^k}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\psi\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and obtained the following decimal representations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & S_k \\
 1 & 0.4606256866 \\
 2 & 0.4825538785 \\
 3 & 0.4974613056 \\
 4 & 0.5012018305 \\
 5 & 0.5002812270 \\
 6 & 0.4998842081
\end{array}
\right)$$ I gave up for $k=7$ (too long).

Comment: Many thanks, since I believe that how converges the series is a difficult issue, I don't know if your calculation is evidence about my claim, that $S=\frac{1}{2}$, or well it tell us that $S\neq\frac{1}{2}$. Any case many thanks for your contribution and help.

Comment: @user243301. You are welcome ! When you plot the partial sums, it is clear that they oscillate less and less. Now, how to prove that the limit is (or not) $\frac 12$, I do not know. I hope and wish that you will get relevant answers. Cheers.

Comment: This morning I've forgotten my first equation, and now I see that that it could be much more easily deduced the result from the first equation. Any case your calculations.